# REST 500 error on list item

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript, permissions

I have a REST request pointing to a list in which I am getting the items. I am using the the `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +'/_api/'` then tagging the path on the end. This list is in the same collection in which I am able to get items from other list with no problems. The list name is "2019 Annual Cooking Class 2". The original name was "2019 Annual Cooking Class_2". I changed it because the underscore was causing issues. I am thinking it is a permissions issue but I can’t figure it out.

This is what the full URL looks like.

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +'/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('2019 Annual Cooking Class 2')/items
```

**Update**
I have full control of the side and when I do the query without the `/items` on the end I get a 200 response and the list object. The error also happens when I try `?$expand=items`.

Comment: Are you able to access this list using browser through site contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is syntax error because of incorrect use of `'`. Try using your URL in below URL format:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +'/_api/web/lists/getByTitle("Display Name of List" )/items';
```

In your case:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +'/_api/web/lists/getByTitle("2019 Annual Cooking Class 2")/items';
```

This list should be in same SharePoint site where you are using this REST call.

**Update**:
If this is not working for you try adding simple `select` clause like given below:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +'/_api/web/lists/getByTitle("2019 Annual Cooking Class 2")/items?$select=Title,ID';
```

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: I updated my question with more details. There might be more going on. I will give this a try and really hope it works.

Comment: Adding the select at the end worked like a charm. THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH. You are a life saver.

Comment: I ran into an issue like this before and it turned out to be because the list had a butt load of columns. I didn’t think this list has that many column to cause that issue so it didn’t cross my mind. Do you this may have been the issue.